# "Action - Go to report" in VS2008 reportviewer not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer

I have an SSRS report which drills through to sub reports via actions.  The report functions correctly in the VS environment, and correct once deployed to the server and viewed through a browser.

The report however is also viewed inside our in-house app via a Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer - and while it renders on screen correctly, clicking the element that would normally take me to a sub-report no longer functions.

I have had a look around and there seemed to be an issue around VS2010 SP1 where this stopped working, however I'm currently stuck with VS2008.  This seems to be the majority of results I'm getting.

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK have found issue.

The text box in question had three place holders. A reference No, A date and an age. I wanted to trigger the sub report if someone clicked on the reference no. While this worked fine in VS and IE, it failed to work in the Microsoft Report Viewer control.

I have now set the action against the containing text box, rather than against a single placeholder/expression within that box. While this has solved the immediate issue that I have, it would not work if you wanted multiple actions from different placeholders in a single text box.

But for now, I'm all good, and all solved.